# How to calculate the mathematical expectation of a matrix?

Tags: probability

Yesterday, one question from my mind, how to calculate the mathematical expectation of a matrix?

For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$. How to calculate $E(A)$ and it have meaning or not?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need a probability measure on the domain of the matrix to compute (if possible) it expected value

Comment: The mathematical expectation of a constant ... is this constant.

Comment: **[1]** A=[1,2;2,1] ; E(A)=E([1,2;2,1])=[E(1),E(2);E(2),E(1)]=[1,2;2,1] **[2]** Constants are not random variables , hence E(C)=C where C is a Constant **[3]** We can calculate Expectation of Matrix A by calculating the Expectation of the Individual Elements of A **[4]** When the **Individual Elements of A are random variables** , we have useful Cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys.